# WPF Error Message <The name "X" does not exist in the namespace "Y">

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio I have a bunch of error messages of the following type:

The name "X" does not exist in the namespace "Y".

I tried the solutions suggested here:

[How do I fix error saying "The type or namespace name X does not exist in the namespace Y"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339521/how-do-i-fix-error-saying-the-type-or-namespace-name-x-does-not-exist-in-the-na)

and here:

[the name <...> does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace <...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051121/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespace)

Nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are completely positive that your namespaces are correctly working together then restart visual studio and issue will be gone. Otherwise there is some wrong with your namespaces :)

Comment: that's one of the solutions I tried out ... it didn't work ... the thing is:  the error messages occurred after I added (+ referenced) an existing project to my solution .... the error messages all refer to namespaces mentioned in one of the xaml-files of the new (added) project ... BUT: I know that the namespaces are correct because before including the project into my solution I ran it separately and everything worked fine ...

Comment: ... so to summarize: the compiler does find the stuff in the namespaces when the project is run as standalone-project ... after adding and referencing the project to another project, the compiler is telling me that the namespaces do not contain the stuff they are supposed to contain

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the project (assembly) where the types are defined in the namespace mapping (`assembly=NameOfTheProject`):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace;assembly=NameOfTheProject"
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on a hello world program, and specifying the assembly name is causing the program to fail to build even though there is only a single assembly in the whole project.  Is there any way to troubleshoot this?