# Visual Studio Broken, Error XAML in WPF, The Name <property> Does Not Exist in The Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, wpf-controls

Suddenly my WPF project had many errors in the XAML section this morning. The user controls stated not exist although it's in my project folder (ProjectFolder\UserControls). I'm currently using VS 2022. Even the DesignHeight is stated as an error as well.

I tried :

- reopen the project
- change target to x86 and back to x64
- change configuration to release and back to debug
- reinstall VS 2022
- run VS 2022 as administrator
- uninstall update (windows update happened the latest day)
  also
- [the name <...> does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace <...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051121/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespace)
- [WPF Error Message <The name "X" does not exist in the namespace "Y"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142444/wpf-error-message-the-name-x-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-y)

but those still don't fix my problem, any leads?

These are the errors I'm seeing:
[image: vs errors]

**Update Dec 5, 2023**
For additional information, the last update of my WPF project is I want to create a component like :

[image: UserControl]

so I tried to tinker the UserControl to be editable from another UserControl.
The XAML codes for the UserControl like

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition" x:Key="ColumnDefinitionLeft">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ColumnDefinitionLeftWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition" x:Key="ColumnDefinitionRight">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ColumnDefinitionRightWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnDefinitionLeft}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnDefinitionRight}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding AttributeName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TextBlock_TextBlock_LeftRight_1}}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AttributeValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TextBlock_TextBlock_LeftRight_1}}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

and the another UserControl that used it like

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"          
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TMDatabasePasser.UserControls"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="350">
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlock_TextBlock_LeftRight_1_A" TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 5 0 5"/>
    </Style>
    <t:GridLength x:Key="ValueWidth">120</t:GridLength>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
             <local:TextBlock_TextBlock_LeftRight_1 ColumnDefinitionLeftWidth="*" ColumnDefinitionRightWidth="{StaticResource ValueWidth}" AttributeName="DO Quantity Left (Kg)" AttributeValue="Value" Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Does the declaration codes may cause all of this :

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
```

for now, I deleted the UserControl and manually using grids and stackpanels, and the error is gone for now, but I still curious about it

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38796783/6292693) (unload-reload the affected project, TMDatabasePasser) work for you?

Comment: @jarmanso7 to open the .csproj, right? unfortunately, that also didn't work (when I tried to just change the .csproj file so I hope it will be refreshed its cache, maybe)

Comment: No. In the solution explorer, right click on your project's name and then select "Unload project"

Comment: Another thing to try: delete the entire .vs folder

Comment: oh, but yes I did it but that also didn't fix the problem,

what is the .vs folder for?, is there any risk if I delete it?, sorry for asking this kind of thing

Comment: [What is the .vs folder used for in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897191/what-is-the-vs-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio-solutions#:~:text=vs%20folder%20is%20required%20by,IIS%20Express%20applicationHost.)